# Why here I got different results?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have next task: Given an array of ints, return true if the array contains no 1's and no 3's.

First version and it's right:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i] == 1 || nums[i] == 3)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

but here's I got many wrong tests:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] != 1 || nums[i] != 3)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Can you explain me reason why does it work like this? I supposed reason is something happened in second if(...)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see at what point `return true;` occurs in your second example?

Comment: Have you tried to validate yourself that the second condition is the *exact inverse* of the first condition?

Comment: Your IDE should highlight the problem with the expression nums[i] != 1 || nums[i] != 3

Comment: You messed up the inverse condition. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Also the inverse of "*there is **one** element for which: ...*" is "***for all** elements is not: ...*".

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes? Do we not encourage people to ask questions that help them to learn? This person doesn't see the mistake in the if statement. I think the question is valid and all this downvoting just encourages the user not to ask any further questions for fear of abuse.

Comment: @Chris Sharp A high quality question would, for example, also contain an example input and outputs for **both** code versions. Together with a description why the output for the second example is not correct. But for me that is not a direct reason to down-vote, at best to cast a close-vote.

Comment: @Zabuza, it's valid to expect input and outputs. I guess I'm just thinking that this person doesn't yet know. I feel an attempt was made to provide relevant information (if incomplete) and that there are ways to encourage the OP without downvotes. And closing seems pretty stern. He just seems to want to understand why the code fails.

Comment: I'll further suggest that if he's reading this exchange then he won't make the same mistake again :)

Comment: Thank you guys, Chris Sharp is right that I am just want to understand why the code was failed and nothing more. Anyway, thanks for your feedback, and in the next time I will post outputs and inputs for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code **should** return `true` if there are **no** `1`s **and no** `3`s.

Let us take a look at your **second code**:

```
// Iterate all values
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    // Return true if value is not 1 OR not 3
    if (nums[i] != 1 || nums[i] != 3)
        return true;
}

// Return false
return false;
```

The key here is the condition `val != 1 || val != 3` which is a **tautology**, i.e. it is `true` in **all cases**. Suppose a value of `5`, it is **not** `1`, so `true` is returned. Now suppose a value of `1`, it is `1` but it is **not** `3`, also `true` is returned.

You would need to substitute `||` by `&&` which means **and**, which also better reflects your textual condition:

> return true if the array contains no 1's **and** no 3's

However you can not directly return `true` if you found the first element which is not `1` and not `3`. You first need to check **all elements**. However you can directly return `false` if you found the first `1` or `3`. And that is exactly the **first version** of your code, which is **correct**.

---

Note that when **negating** a conditions you need to negate all **quantifiers** and **operators** too.

The first code realizes an approach using this logic:

- *Not (there exists one element which is `1` or `3`)*
- `¬(∃ e : e = 1 ∨ e = 3)`

When now solving the negation you receive this logic:

- ***All*** elements are **not** `1` **and not** `3`
- `∀ e : e ≠ 1 ∧ e ≠ 3`

So `∃` (*exists*) turns to `∀` (*for all*), `=` to `≠` and `∨` (*or*) to `∧` (*and*).

Comment: thanks for your explanation, now I understand why it's failed :)

Answer (score 1):

## Why the first one works

It returns false if any item is not 1 or 3, and true if no items match

## Why the second one does not work

It returns true all the time (if any item is not equal to 1 or 3, and no integer is equal to both 1 and 3), the only way to get false is to pass it an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing a short-circuit evaluation. The first version is right. In the second version, you prematurely return `true` when you encounter a number that isn't `1` or `3` - which is **every** number, since `1` is not `3` and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

For the second answer, you are using `OR` instead of `AND`. Hence whatever value you provide, it will always enter into the if condition.

Hope this helps.